# Google App engine template unicode decoding problem

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, unicode

When trying to render a Django template file in Google App Engine

> from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
>
> templatepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), 'template.html')
> self.response.out.write (template.render( templatepath , template_values))

I come across the  following error:

> <type
> 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>:
> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2
> in position 17692: ordinal not in
> range(128)
> args = ('ascii', '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
> Str...07/a-beautiful-method-to-find-peace-of-mind/
> -->
>  ', 17692, 17693, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
> encoding = 'ascii'
> end = 17693
> message = ''
> object = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
> Str...07/a-beautiful-method-to-find-peace-of-mind/
> -->
> reason = 'ordinal not in range(128)'
> start = 17692

It seems that the underlying django template engine has assumed the "ascii" encoding, which should have been "utf-8".
Anyone who knows what might have caused the trouble and how to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of your DEFAULT_CHARSET? <http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/> might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, turns out the rendered results returned by the template needs to be decoded first:

> self.response.out.write (template.render( templatepath , template_values).decode('utf-8') )

A silly mistake, but thanks for everyone's answers anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Django 0.96 or Django 1.0? You can check by looking at your main.py and seeing if it contains the following:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.0')
```

If you're using Django 1.0, both FILE_CHARSET and DEFAULT_CHARSET should default to 'utf-8'. If your template is saved under a different encoding, just set FILE_CHARSET to whatever that is.

If you're using Django 0.96, you might want to try directly reading the template from the disk and then manually handling the encoding.

e.g., replace

`template.render( templatepath , template_values)`

with

`Template(unicode(template_fh.read(), 'utf-8')).render(template_values)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in your text editor that the template is encoded in utf-8?